# Spring & Jackson - JSON list to custom XML

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, jackson

I have the following input in JSON format (the address list can be longer) :

```
{
    "name": "Edward",
    "address": [
        {
            "streetName": "value1",
            "city": "value2"
        },
        {
            "streetName": "value3",
            "city": "value4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to convert it to XML like this :

```
<root>
    <name>Edward</name>
    <streetName1>value1</streetName1>
    <city1>value2</city1>
    <streetName2>value3</streetName2>
    <city2>value4</city2>
</root>
```

I tried doing this:

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
private List<Address> address = new ArrayList<>();
```

But what I got was :

```
<root>
    <name>Edward</name>
    <address>
        <streetName>value1</streetName>
        <city>value2</city>
    </address>
    <address>
        <streetName>value3</streetName>
        <city>value4</city>
    </address>
</root>
```

Please assist me in getting to the desired format ! Any help would be much appreciated ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to solve your issue with a custom serializer, so if you have a `Person` class like below :

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root")
@JsonSerialize(using = PersonSerializer.class)
public class Person {

    private String name;

    private List<Address> address = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

You can build a custom `PersonSerializer` serializer class extending the [`JsonSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html) class like below :

```
public class PersonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Person> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Person t, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {
        String streetName = "streetName";
        String city = "city";
        int nStreet = 1;
        int nCity = 1;
        jg.writeStartObject();
        jg.writeStringField("name", t.getName());
        for (Address address : t.getAddress()) {

            jg.writeStringField(streetName + String.valueOf(nStreet++), address.getStreetName());
            jg.writeStringField(city + String.valueOf(nCity++), address.getCity());

        }
        jg.writeEndObject();
    }

}
```

Then you can serialize your `Person` object like below obtaining the xml result you expect :

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
//you already have your person object to serialize
String result = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(person);
```

Comment: Great ! Thank u!

Comment: @ROBlackSnail You are welcome :-)